# representation of files and folder-tree of Google Drive folder using Python API

Tags: python, class, google-drive-api

I want to list a google drive folders and files in nested json tree using python class.

i want each data point of structure should be object, i want to wrap whole script in class

Tree should be like this

```
[
{
"name":<folder_name>,
"id":<folder_id>,
"type":'folder',
 "children":[
        {
        "name":<folder_name>,
        "id":<folder_id>,
        "type":'folder',
         "children":[
         {
            "name":<folder_name>,
            "id":<folder_id>,
            "type":'folder',
             "children":[..........]
        },
        {
            "name":<file_name>,
            "id":<file_id>,
            "type":'file',
        }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":<file_name>,
        "id":<file_id>,
        "type":'file',
        }
]
},
{
"name":<file_name>,
"id":<file_id>,
"type":'file',
},
......................
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but you have to implement it yourself.

1. First, get files with a parent of the rootFolder.
2. After getting the files, check if it is a folder. If yes, check if it has files under.

   2.1 Insert data to `children` property
3. Repeat process until you've successfully listed all files.

References:

- [Python Google Drive API - list the entire drive file tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22110005/5995040)
- [Create a Tree View of your Google Drive](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-tree/21198/)
- [List all Google Drive Files and Folders](https://ctrlq.org/code/19923-google-drive-files-list?_ga=2.105157258.801112406.1515227643-1515226084.1497947047)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Need some refactoring, but works. Just add values to `dictionary`, for example `x.name: x.make_dict()` for every element.

```
import logging
import copy

import connect


logger = logging.getLogger('importer')


class DriveObj():

    def __init__(self, drive_obj):
        self.id = drive_obj.get('id')
        self.name = drive_obj.get('name')

    def make_dict(self):
        props = copy.deepcopy(vars(self))
        del props['name']
        return props

    @property
    def parents(self):
        try:
            return service.files().get(fileId=self.id,
                                       fields='parents').execute()['parents']
        except KeyError:
            return []


class Directory(DriveObj):

    def __init__(self, drive_obj):
        super().__init__(drive_obj)
        self.mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        assert drive_obj.get('mimeType') == self.mimeType, 'Not dir :('
        self.children = []

    def add_content(self, drive_obj):
        self.children.append(drive_obj)


class Document(DriveObj):

    def __init__(self, drive_obj):
        super().__init__(drive_obj)
        assert 'vnd.google-apps.folder' not in drive_obj.get('mimeType')
        self.mimeType = drive_obj.get('mimeType')


def get_filelist(service):
    return service.files().list().execute()


def get_content(service):
    content = list()
    for drive_obj in get_filelist(service)['files']:
        try:
            content.append(Directory(drive_obj))
        except AssertionError:
            content.append(Document(drive_obj))
    return content


def find_id(content, id):
    for drive_obj in content:
        logger.debug('Got {}'.format(drive_obj.id))
        if drive_obj.id == id:
            logger.debug('Find id in {}'.format(drive_obj.id))
            return drive_obj
        elif type(drive_obj) == Directory and drive_obj.children:
            logger.debug('{} has children'.format(drive_obj.id))
            result = find_id(drive_obj.children, id)
            if result:
                return result


def create_corr_structure(content):
    for obj in content:
        if obj.parents:
            for parent in obj.parents:
                parent_obj = find_id(content, parent)
                if parent_obj:
                    parent_obj.add_content(obj)
                else:
                    logger.debug(
                        'There is no parent directory for {}'.format(obj.name))
    content[:] = [value for value in content if not value.parents]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    structure = dict()
    service = connect.connect_drive()
    content = get_content(service)
    create_corr_structure(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(your creds, scope)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
def check_for_subfolders(folder_id):
    new_sub_patterns = {}
    folders = service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and parents in '"+folder_id+"' and trashed = false",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",pageSize=400).execute()
    all_folders = folders.get('files', [])
    all_files = check_for_files(folder_id)
    n_files = len(all_files)
    n_folders = len(all_folders)
    old_folder_tree = folder_tree
    if n_folders != 0:
        for i,folder in enumerate(all_folders):
            folder_name =  folder['name']
            subfolder_pattern = old_folder_tree + '/'+ folder_name
            new_pattern = subfolder_pattern
            new_sub_patterns[subfolder_pattern] = folder['id']
            print('New Pattern:', new_pattern)
            all_files = check_for_files(folder['id'])
            n_files =len(all_files)
            new_folder_tree = new_pattern 
            if n_files != 0:
                for file in all_files:
                    file_name = file['name']
                    new_file_tree_pattern = subfolder_pattern + "/" + file_name
                    new_sub_patterns[new_file_tree_pattern] = file['id']
                    print("Files added :", file_name)
            else:
                print('No Files Found')
    else:
        all_files = check_for_files(folder['id'])
        n_files = len(all_files)
        if n_files != 0:
            for file in all_files:
                file_name = file['name']
                subfolders[folder_tree + '/'+file_name] = file['id']
                new_file_tree_pattern = subfolder_pattern + "/" + file_name
                new_sub_patterns[new_file_tree_pattern] = file['id']
                print("Files added :", file_name)
    return new_sub_patterns 
def check_for_files(folder_id):
    other_files = service.files().list(q="mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and parents in '"+folder_id+"' and trashed = false",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",pageSize=400).execute()
    all_other_files = other_files.get('files', [])   
    return all_other_files
def get_folder_tree(folder_id):
    global folder_tree
    sub_folders = check_for_subfolders(folder_id)
    for i,sub_folder_id in enumerate(sub_folders.values()):
        folder_tree = list(sub_folders.keys() )[i]
        print('Current Folder Tree : ', folder_tree)
        folder_ids.update(sub_folders)
        print('****************************************Recursive Search Begins**********************************************')
        try:
            get_folder_tree(sub_folder_id)
        except:
            print('---------------------------------No furtherance----------------------------------------------')
    return folder_ids
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does. What it has to do with the OPs code? This clearly does not help either the OP or some passerby with the same predicament.

Comment: Code helps to retrieve complete file and folder structure in gdrive through recursive searching. Function get_folder_tree is called within itself so that the process continues until all files and folders are listed  with their google file ids

Answer (score 0):

In general, Google drive is not a typical tree structure (folders are labels and a file can have multiple parents).

BUT, I would consider using a tree visualization library like [treelib](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**Below is a full solution for printing your Google drive file system recursively.**

```
from treelib import Node, Tree

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


def get_children(root_folder_id):
    str = "\'" + root_folder_id + "\'" + " in parents and trashed=false"
    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': str}).GetList()
    return file_list

def get_folder_id(root_folder_id, root_folder_title):
    file_list = get_children(root_folder_id)
    for file in file_list:
        if(file['title'] == root_folder_title):
            return file['id']

def add_children_to_tree(tree, file_list, parent_id):
    for file in file_list:
        tree.create_node(file['title'], file['id'], parent=parent_id)
        print('parent: %s, title: %s, id: %s' % (parent_id, file['title'], file['id']))


def populate_tree_recursively(tree,parent_id):
    children = get_children(parent_id)
    add_children_to_tree(tree, children, parent_id)
    if(len(children) > 0):
        for child in children:
            populate_tree_recursively(tree, child['id'])



def main():
    root_folder_title = "your-root-folder"
    root_folder_id = get_folder_id("root", root_folder_title)

    tree = Tree()
    tree.create_node(root_folder_title, root_folder_id)
    populate_tree_recursively(tree, root_folder_id)
    tree.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```